# js use query string to change selected option

Tags: javascript

Trying to change selected option based on anchor that is clicked on a different page. Example of an anchor:

```
<a href="booking.html?selected=one">Book Now</a>
```

And select:

```
<select name="package">
    <option id="one" value="sOne">Single Game</option>
    (5 more options)
</select>
```

And I currently have the following js in my code:

```
function selectPack() {
    var queryString = getQueryStrings();
    var select = $('package')[0];
    console.dir(select);
    select.selectedIndex = queryString["selected"];
}
window.onload = selectPack;
```

I have tried another method but that didn't work, I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: use the window.location.search to get the query strings

Comment: from a href, you would just grab the attr and then use split on the ? to find the queries.

Comment: `selectedIndex` expects index number of the option within the select, not an id or value string

Comment: The 2 in my previous comment also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the select by saying `$('select[name="package"]')`. As it is now it's looking for an element called `<package>`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer to his inherint problem.

Answer (score 0):

`var qs = 'ID'` ID is the query string of the ID you are trying to select which must exist in select list.

```
$('select[name="package"] option[id="'+qs+'"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

EDIT:
More complete example:

html:

```
<a href="booking.html?selected=one">Book Now</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var qs = window.location.href;
var q = qs.split('?selected=')[1];

$('select[name="package"] option[id="'+q+'"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean in the first part. Could maybe give me an example?

Comment: I was assuming you had code which provided a the select list option you are looking for. This code is just to use that to then choose that option within the select list.

Comment: I have updated my code, it still isn't working. It is definitely running because it is in the same function as another piece of code which is running